# Cómo guardar los valores de un array en base de datos con RoR y JqueryAJAX

Tags: ajax, array, ruby-on-rails

Quiero guardar los valores de unos checkboxes generados por un ciclo each. En el JS tengo una variable (member)donde obtengo los valores. Al momento de guardar, en consola me dice `unpermitted parameter:member` y por lo tanto no me agrega esos valores a la base de datos.

```
$("#updateActivity").click(function(){
  id= $("#id_activity").val();
  var member = $.map($('input[name="activityMembers"]:checked'), function(c){return c.value; });
  var ajax_url = "activities/" + id + ".json";

  $.ajax({
    url:ajax_url,
    method:"PUT",
    data:{
      activity:{
        name:$("#activityNameModal").val(),
        description:$("#activityDescription").val(),
        enddate:$("#activityEndDate").val(),
        member: member
      }
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log (data)
    }
  })
})


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Miembros designados</label>
  <% Member.all.each do |member| %>
    <label>
      <input name="activityMembers" type="checkbox" id="activityMember_<%= member.id %>" value="<%= member.id %>">
      <span><%= member.name%> </span>
    </label>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

activities_controller.erb:

```
def show
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @activity }
  end
end

def update
  @activity_id = params[:activity_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @activity.update(activity_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @activity, notice: 'La actividad ha sido actualizada.' }
      format.json { render :json => @activity }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :description, :enddate)
end
```

log:

```
Started PUT "/activities/83.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-16 11:05:20 -0500
Processing by ActivitiesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"activity"=>{"name"=>"Tarea 1", "description"=>"Agregar registros a BD", "enddate"=>"2018-04-01", "members"=>["1", "2", "3"]}, "id"=>"83"}
  Activity Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`id` = 83 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: :members
   (4.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE `activities` SET `description` = 'Agregar registros a BD', `enddate` = '2018-04-01', `updated_at` = '2018-04-16 16:05:20' WHERE `activities`.`id` = 83
   (3.9ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 56ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)
```

Comment: No estás incluyendo  `member` en tu lista  de parámetros permitidos en tu controlador (a través de _strong parameters_); ¿podrías compartir el log completo y el código de tu controlador?

Comment: claro que sí, en un momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas incluir `members` en la lista de parámetros permitidos, es decir, dentro de `permit` en el método `activity_params` en el controlador:

```
def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :description, :enddate, member_ids: [])
end
```

Además, es importante cambiar el nombre del parámetro de `members` a `members_ids` para que pueda ser reconocido por *rails*; por lo tanto, también deberás actualizar el *script*:

```
$("#updateActivity").click(function(){
  id= $("#id_activity").val();
  var member = $.map($('input[name="activityMembers"]:checked'), function(c){return c.value; });
  var ajax_url = "activities/" + id + ".json";

  $.ajax({
    url:ajax_url,
    method:"PUT",
    data:{
      activity:{
        name:$("#activityNameModal").val(),
        description:$("#activityDescription").val(),
        enddate:$("#activityEndDate").val(),
        member_ids: member
      }
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log (data)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Ya lo intenté así y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @HarimCaballero ¿Podrías mostrar el log completo del error? [Agrégalo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/155647/edit) en la pregunta.

Comment: ya anexé el log @Gerry

Comment: @HarimCaballero Al parecer tu el código del AJAX tiene un _typo_ pues el log indica que envías `members` no `member`; por lo tanto agrega `members` en el `permit`; checa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, lo agregué en el permit y nada

Comment: @HarimCaballero ¿Te sigue mostrando el mismo error?

Comment: Si, lo mismo @Gerry

Comment: @HarimCaballero Probablemente tengas algún otro _typo_ en tu código, o bien, sea un controlador distinto en el que estás haciendo el cambio. ¿Podrías verificar? El error que muestras debe corregirse al actualizar `activity_params`. Si tienes tu proyecto en Github dame el _link_ del repositorio y así puedo ver si el error está en otro lado.

Comment: Te paso el link del repositorio: https://github.com/harim95/tasks.git

Comment: @HarimCaballero Pasé de alto que estás pasando un arreglo, por lo tanto debes indicarlo como tal en `permit`; revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Funcionó!. Muchas gracias @Gerry

Comment: @HarimCaballero Súper! Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma). Suerte!

Comment: ¿Qué podría hacer para marcar los checboxes con los registros desde BD?

Comment: @HarimCaballero Primero debes incluir los `members` asociados a cada `activity` en el `json` que regresas al abrir la modal. Después utiliza esos datos para evaluar si el valor del `checkbox` (o bien, el `id` del `member`) está incluido en el objeto (en la respuesta del `json`) y, en caso que así sea, entonces marcas la casilla (esto lo puedes hacer con JavaScript/jQuery). Inténtalo y si tienes problemas vuelve y publica una nueva pregunta.